# Is this a MOSFET and if so which legs are which?

Tags: transistors, identification

I have this TO-220 package transistor from the (inline) regulator of an electrical hotplate.

[image: Photo of transistor#1]

[image: Photo of transistor#2]

The markings on it *appear* to be

```
G21
6
9146
```

and the logo at the start of the last line would suggest that it is a Motorola device - but that is not visible in the photo.

After some simple checks with a DMM, the resistance between pin 1 and 3 (and vice versa) is 56 Ω. Between pins 2 and 3, the resistance is 3.5-4 MΩ and in the same magnitude between pin 3 and 2.

I can't find the datasheet when googling Motorola/MOSFET/9146/Transistor and combinations thereof.

I would like to know whether this *is* actually a MOSFET and if so, which pin is which? Is it the usual GDS, or something else? A link to a datasheet would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is 9146 the yyww code?

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't thought of that - mid November 1991... it *is* rather an old cooker/hotplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a [IRF621 N-channel enhancement mode silicon gate TMOS](https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-9088453381472243325).

Comment: Ah, it's a *6* and not a *G*. Thanks.

Comment: Did Motorola second source that part?

Comment: @ThePhoton Looks like Motorola, GE, ST and even some Chinese outfit [Inchange](http://www.iscsemi.cn/) made it. Hard finding an original International Rectifier datasheet though.